# Local const in recursion call

Tags: python, memory-management, recursion

Well... Code first.

```
def magic(node):
  spells_dict = {"AR_OP":ar_op_magic, "PRE_OP":pre_op_magic}
  if node:
    if node.text in spells_dict:
      return spells_dict[node.text](node)
    else:
      return magic(node.l) + magic(node.r)
  else:
    return ""
```

During recursion calls there will be created a lot of spells_dict copies. I know that I can make that dict global, but I don't want, because this dict related to magic function only. So, I can create some class and put spells_dict and function to it, but it don't looks like a good solution.

Is there any way how I can do it with only one copy of spells_dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with a `MAGIC_SPELLS` constant. You can locale it near the `magic` function, so you know, the belong together:

```
def magic_default(node):
    return magic(node.l) + magic(node.r)

MAGIC_SPELLS = {
    'AR_OP': ar_op_magic,
    'PRE_OP': pre_op_magic,
}

def magic(node):
    if node:
        func = MAGIC_SPELLS.get(node.text, magic_default)
        return func(node)
    return ""
```

Comment: But this is make spells_dict global approach, and I try find another solution. By the way, do you forget declare MAGIC_SPELLS as global inside magic function?

Comment: `MAGIC_SPELLS` is a constant and is not changed, so no need for global. And what's your problem with global constants?

Comment: @Daniel Show him how to put a dict into a default argument for a localized function parameter. That's the most Pythonic way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Shashank: no it isn't. Default arguments are not for hiding variables. Why should this be pythonic?

Comment: Well that's what I would do (out of laziness), but anyways if you don't like that approach, then you can use a closure to "hide the variable" ("make the variable private" would be a better way to describe it), make it local, and make it so that it's only created once, all at the same time. Either way, you can easily get rid of the global. The reason I say the default argument approach is Pythonic is because it's not common to be able to do such in other languages.

Comment: @Daniel After your answer I rediscover meaning of global keyword. And now it is acceptable approach to me. Thanks.